# java.io.file cannot be cast to custom class

Tags: java, inheritance

My code:

```
FileChooser prompt = new FileChooser();
prompt.setTitle("Odaberi fajl");
source = (Source) prompt.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
```

where source is a class that extends File as such:

```
    import java.io.File;

public class Source extends File {

    public Source(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
    }
}
```

returns an error when trying to cast to Source. I have no idea what is causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileChooser` returns a `File`. What makes you think you can cast it to `Source`? It is not a `Source`.

What you want to do is one of:

1. Make `Source` encasulate a `File` and provide whatever custom methods you need, delegating to the contained `File` as appropriate.

   ```
   public class Source {
       private File f;
       public Source(File f) {
           this.f = f;
       }
       // Custom methods
       ...
       // Delegating methods
       public boolean exists() {
           return f.exists();
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Extend `File` as you are doing, but provide a constructor that takes another `File` (i.e. a copy constructor) and instantiates the `Source` using the data from the passed `File`.

   ```
   public class Source extends File {
       public Source(File f) {
           super(f.getAbsolutePath());
       }
       // Custom methods
       ...
   }
   ```

Then instantiate as follows:

```
FileChooser prompt = new FileChooser();
prompt.setTitle("Odaberi fajl");
source = new Source(prompt.showOpenDialog(new Stage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what casting does.

Casting is a compile-time directive; it tells the compiler that the operation being performed (`showOpenDialog()` in your case) is going to return an object that matches the cast. If that turns out not to be true, then the program will throw an `IllegalCastException` at runtime. It is up to the programmer who writes the cast to ensure that the cast is going to be correct at runtime. The compiler will tell you if there is no possible way for it to be correct, in many cases, but cannot tell you in all cases.

`FileChooser` was written without knowledge of your `Source` class, so it is not possible for it to return a `Source` object. If the cast had succeeded, you would be allowed (by the compiler) to call methods from `Source` on the resulting object, and that would clearly be incorrect.

One thing to realize about casting is that, except in very limited circumstances involving boxed primitives, casting does not change the object referred to at all. Its purpose is to let the compiler know that operations will be legal on the resulting class.

As an aside, it helps enormously when asking a question to say what happens, not just 'returns an Error'. Is that a compile or runtime error? What does the error say? Please remember that for questions you ask in the future.